# Sorting by a GenericIPAddressField in Django admin site

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

How can I numerically sort a model by a GenericIPAddressField in Django's admin site?

Using Meta.ordering in the model sorts it like this:

- 192.168.1.1
- 192.168.1.15
- 192.168.1.9

But I want it sorted like this:

- 192.168.1.1
- 192.168.1.9
- 192.168.1.15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution you could look at using is converting the IP address to int, storing both in the database.

Basically you take the IP address and split it on each `.`.

This will give you something like:

```
Octet 1: 192
Octet 2: 168
Octet 3: 1
Octet 4: 10
```

You then use the following maths to give you an integer which can be ordered.

```
(Octet1 * 256^3) + (Octet2 * 256^2) + (Octet3 * 256) + (Octet4)
3221225472 + 11010048 + 256 + 10 = 3232235786
```

More information can be found here: http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/IP2Integer.jsp

Comment: If anybody else does this, remember to use a BigIntegerField and not an IntegerField in the model. An IntegerField isn't big enough. Also, this approach only supports IPv4 addresses (which is fine for me right now).

Comment: Beware that this won't work with IPv6. It's somewhat irresponsible to design an application in this age that locks you out of IPv6 support.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the answer you wanted to hear, but your database probably doesn't support an IP address field type, so Django uses a text field type with text sorting semantics.

PostgreSQL has native support for IP addresses (both IPv4 and IPv6), including natural sorting.

Comment: You're right. I was using MySQL which doesn't support IP addresses natively. It would be nice though if Django abstracted away this problem and implemented natural sorting for its GenericIPAddressField (maybe they have since then, I haven't checked).

Answer (score 0):

Based on intgr's comment about IPv6, I just wanted to include the code I ended up using, which is based on Matt's approach of storing an integer version of the IP but plays nicely with IPv6.

```
import socket, struct
def ip_to_int(ip):
    ip = unicode(ip)
    try:
        return struct.unpack('!I', socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET, ip))[0]
    except socket.error:
        try:
            hi, lo = struct.unpack('!QQ', socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET6, ip))
            return (hi << 64) | lo
        except socket.error:
            return 0
```

Unfortunately I can't remember now if I wrote this myself or if I found it online somewhere, so I can't give credit if credit is due.